# Javascript: Make an array value the key of new array

Tags: javascript

I have an array as follows:

```
d=[
     {name: 'cheese'},
     {name: 'meat'}
]
```

i want to convert it to something like this:

```
d_new={
    cheese: 0,
    meat:1
}
```

i've tried with:

```
d_new = d.map(item => {
   return({item.name : 0})
})
```

but throws error at `.`: `, expected`

Any idea

Comment: "Dictionary" is not a data structure in Javascript. Your input's syntax is not valid either - objects cannot have duplicate keys

Comment: Additionally: `map` is a function that works on arrays, not objects. If you want to use `map`, you need to convert your object into an array that makes sense first.

Comment: `d={
     name: 'cheese',
     name: 'meat'
}` is not an array... arrays do not have keys ;)

Comment: modified, does this makes more sense?

Comment: Your input's syntax is *still* invalid. Like I said in the first comment, objects cannot have duplicate keys. As @acincognito said, `.map` does not work on objects either.

Comment: right, this looks better

Comment: updated my answer below :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That's the way I would do this task in JS:

```js
const d = [{
    name: 'cheese'
  },
  {
    name: 'meat'
  }
];

const keys = d.map(item => item.name);

const result = {};

keys.forEach((key, index) => {
  result[key] = index;
});

console.log(result);
```

---

EDIT

For reference, another answer from the comment by 3limin4t0r below:

```js
const d = [{
    name: 'cheese'
  },
  {
    name: 'meat'
  }
];
const d_new = Object.fromEntries(d.map((obj, index) => [obj.name, index]));
console.log(d_new);
```

Comment: thanks, this works. I thought i could work only with map ;)

Comment: @Alvaro You can. `Object.fromEntries(d.map((obj, index) => [obj.name, index]))`

Comment: great, I was looking for this!